# Free fall in a centrifugal space ship?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centrifugal-force, free-fall

I have read the basics on O'Neil cylinders. A tube with a five mile diameter rotating almost 23 times an hour would produce forces akin to earthlike gravity at the rim. There would be a space in the center where weightlessness would occur. The tube is filled with air.

My primary question is that if a person were floating in this space, no restraints, no walkway and found their way out of that space (center towards rim, starting at a modest velocity, like a run), what would the effect be? I assume they would accelerate due to air currents and eventually crash into a wall at the rim, but that this wouldn't look exactly like a gravity free fall. But I'm not sure. It seems like it's a slow moving centrifuge that would eventually accelerate said person.

The two subsequent things I'm mostly interested in are what the chances of survival are and what kind of mitigating effects could be used. Would a parachute do anything or act like a sail, speeding one up?

Comment: Would [worldbuilding.se] SE be a better home for this question?

Comment: Worldbuilding physics questions are definitely rigorous physics. It looks like your activity there doesn't seem science-y, but you will surely get rigorous and accurate physics descriptions. So a question about a hypothetical spaceship is definitely better suited to worldbuilding. Physics in imaginary settings belongs there.

Comment: @Chair Sounds like an interesting question about the physical effects in real, not imaginary conditions (e.g. no wormholes). If he phrased it in terms of a centrifuge without referring to a spaceship, you would not have an objection while it would still be the same question. Perhaps we should redirect all wormhole questions here to the wordbuilding instead due to imaginary settings?

Comment: @safesphere it is an interesting question. But as far as I've explored the [physics tag on worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/physics) the mix they have includes several similar hypothetical yet not physically impossible scenarios. Perhaps I'll look around on their meta and ours to see if there's any definitive community agreement about the overlap of our scopes. I'm inclined to say that it's Worldbuilding content because it's about a centrifugal spaceship and those things are classically fictitious.

Comment: @safesphere Yep, the tag excerpt for 'physics' on worldbuilding says "For questions regarding the physics relevant to fictitious worlds. General physics may be off-topic." This clearly falls under 'physics in a fictitious setting of a centrifugal space ship."

Comment: There is no gravity inside the cylinder, only weightlessness and the wind. Without air one could float just an inch above the rotating floor and never fall. However, the wind over the 5km distance would be strong enough to completely involve a falling person in rotation. So for all practical purposes there would be the appearance of gravity inside proportional to the current radius. A falling person would accelerate gradually and crash. Things with a higher density would fall slower and on a bigger angle.

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking the time to answer my question. I removed the why of what I was asking, since it was not relevant to what I wanted to know. I did not want and was not interested in the type of answer one would expect from world building, I just wanted mechanics. Take care! :)

Comment: "A tube with a five mile diameter rotating almost 23 times an hour would produce forces akin to earthlike gravity at the rim."  Centripetal acceleration appears to be closer to 13g, not earthlike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an object moves from the center of a rotating craft radially outwards, they experience something known as the [Coriolis force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coriolis_force). This fictitious force arises due to the difference in rotational speed between inner and outer radii (outer points travel faster). Without going too much into the technicalities, it basically means that an object moving radially outward will be deflected "backward" with respect to the craft, while an object moving radially inwards will be deflected "forward" with respect to the craft.

This force depends on the velocity at which one walks outwards from the center to the edge. In your case, we assume that the person is walking at $5 \; \mathrm{m/s}$ outwards, which is a typical speed, along a hallway pointing directly outwards. Using the equation for the acceleration due to the Coriolis force, $2\Omega \times v$, where $\Omega$ is the angular velocity, we get a value of about $0.5 \; \mathrm{m/s^2}$ (towards the wall of the hallway). This will definitely be noticeable, but is unlikely to cause major damage (provided the hallway isn't too wide).

In addition, the person will also gain a velocity of $v = r \Omega$ with respect to the rim of the tube when they reach it, where $r$ is the radius of the tube. This value is about $320 \; \mathrm{m/s}$, which can prove fatal.

Comment: No damage if they are on a walk way, but if there is no walkway and the individual is left to accelerate until they hit something (an outer wall), I assume, even .5 m/s is going to get you moving quickly eventually. I think that answers my question, if I'm understanding correctly.

Comment: @Kirk: You are absolutely correct; if it is an open space and the object moves very fast (radially outward), it will eventually crash into something with a large impact. This problem might be overcome by walking slowly and letting the friction from the floor gradually bring your rotational speed up to match the faster speed at the destination.

Comment: What is this floor you keep talking about? The person starts out floating in the air, in the middle of a rotating cylinder which is a zero-g environment (apart from the centrifugal gravity). The OP wants to know what happens if the person somehow moves away from the axis.

Comment: The person is nowhere near the wall of the cylinder... until they crash into it. And the main thrust of the question is how do you figure out the speed the person would have when they crash.

Comment: @PM 2Ring: I do not understand what you mean by "nowhere near the wall of the cylinder". The person is *inside* it. Are you talking about the centrifugal force?

Comment: It's a large cylinder, with a radius around 4km. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/O%27Neill_cylinder

Comment: @PM 2Ring: The person will not experience any centrifugal force if they start from the center and move radially outwards. They will only have a tangential speed of $v = r \omega$ with respect to the cylinder before they reach it. I have added this to the answer as the OP was not very clear which direction the person is traveling in.